# accessing elements of an multiply instantiated module

Tags: verilog

I am trying to write a behavioral code in verilog  describing a RAM that has 256 locations, each of size 64-bits. so, I created a module `RAM_cell` that has output `data_out` and input `data_in`,both of width 64 bits. then, I created another module called `RAM` within which, I declared,

```
RAM_cell mem [255:0] (data_out,data_in,rd);
```

the RAM reads from 8-bit `Maddr` when rd=1 or writes to `Maddr`when rd=0.Now 
in the module `RAM`, which has `Mdata_out` as output, for read operation, I wrote,

```
always @(posedge clk)
initial
begin
if (rd == 1'b1)
Mdata_in = mem[Maddr].data_out;
end
```

that didn't work. the compiler threw error that the indexing variable is not a constant.
Why didn't it work? what are the other ways (Other than using `case` statement using 256 control signals..!!).

Thank you. Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS: I can upload all necessary data (like exact code,compiler output,etc..) on demand.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the generate..endgenerate. the compiler allocates the number of instances you required. The array index will become a part of the name. 
So it will create 256 uniquely named instances like m[0], m[1], ... where '[]' will be just a part of the generated name. You cannot index into it. There is no such name as 'mem[Maddr]'

So, instead you should index your data_out.

I do not recommend using this construct at all due to confusing syntax around it. Instead use a generate block and a for loop to instantiate it. In this case you would have a complete control over what you pass to it:

```
generate
   for(geni = 0; geni < 256; geni++) begin: loop
        RAM_cell mem (data_out[geni],data_in[geni],rd);
   end


endgenerate

always @* begin
     ...
     Mdata_in = data_out[Maddr];
     ...
end
```

If you insist on XMR (non synthesizable) to access internal signals in the 'mem', you can put your always block inside the 'for' loop and use 'mem.sig'

Comment: Thank you Serge. but, after this modification, do I have to change the size of data_out,data_in in the module RAM_cell?. the compiler again throws an error that (say, data_out [2] is OUT OF RANGE), the values are out of range.
Do you recommend to change it to

output [63:0] data_out [255:0]; ??
in the module itself? Thanks.

Comment: you never explained how it was defined before. I would expect that you declare data_out in the main module (in system verilog syntax) as "logic [7:0] data_out[255:0];" in this case your output int he module mem will look like "module mem(output logic[7:0] data_out, ...)"